# AngularJS and IE8 - unsupported property or method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I'm working on supporting an existing AngularJS application to work with Internet Explorer 8.
For routing, I've used the [AngularUI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) framework. It provides the `ui-sref` directive to navigate to other states.

In the console of the IE8 Developer Tools, I get the following error for every element with the `ui-sref=""` attribute.

> TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method `<a class=ng-binding href="" ui-sref="state-name">`

#### Screenshot

[image]

#### Original HTML

```
<a ui-sref="state-name">Go to My State</a>
```

Probably because of this error, the navigation doesn't work. When I click the link, nothing happens.

Is there anyone who experienced similar problems before? Or can possibly guide me into the right direction?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem here is that IE8 doesn't support the method `indexOf()` natively.

The solution is to include a [ES5 shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim), which provides support for `indexOf()`.

Comment: this is just wonderful, i wish angularJS doc has this built in.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `data-ui-sref` rather than `ui-sref`

Comment: Same issue. Then I get `TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method <a class=ng-binding href="" data-ui-sref="state-name">`.

Comment: what version of Angular are you using? looks like there are a few relavent bugs issued: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/576 and https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/350

Comment: I'm using AngularJS v1.2.2. For UIRouter I'm using a custom build, based on one of the latest commits atm: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/tree/861238049b1a098c1d98983d53f7db431a0462fa

Comment: Thank you both for looking into this. See my answer, which solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check your method signature and argument expected is in synchronization. It fixed in my case.